# In preparing for segue, how to pass data to a child UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

In a typical segue in iOS, view controller `A` is segueing to `B`, and I override `prepare(for:sender:)` in `A`, to pass some data to `B`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let b = segue.destination as! ViewControllerB
    b.someData = ...
```

But if `B` has an embedded child view controller, it will not be loaded yet at this point. Is there a recommended way to pass data to the embedded child view controller?

I could define the fields on `ViewControllerB`, and then have it pass them to the child in it's `viewDidLoad` method. (At that point the child view controller *is* present in B's `childViewControllers` array.) But, this seems a bit ugly to me.

Comment: What about direct communication between the grandchild and the grandparent with a delegate?

Comment: Well, if you have A->B->C, and you need to pass data from A->C, you could set this to B, and inside B do the same to set to C.

Answer (score 0):

To follow the OOP principles, particularly "Abstraction". 
ViewControllerA shouldn't know anything about how ViewControllerB does the job. If ViewControllerB loads any controls on its own, then it's ViewControllerB's business. The job of ViewControllerA is to supply ViewControllerB with everything it needs to do the job. 
So yeah, I'd use viewDidLoad event to load the childViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method in view controller B, for example

```
public configureChildVC(data: Any) {
// in here set data to child vc
}
```

and then in prepare for segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let b = segue.destination as! ViewControllerB
    b.configureChildVC(data: whatever)
}
```